# Cannot upload an image in django using ImageField

Tags: django, image

I am writing my first django app that uses the ImageField and I am having
difficulty.  The problem is that my images are not uploading.  I have looked at
as many examples that I can find.  And I'm not sure what's going wrong here.

I am trying to verify that my photos are uploading by looking in the location
of the `upload_to` directory.  When the form is displayed in the web page the
correct upload file button is displayed.  When I hit submit, the code below executes, 
but no images are ever uploaded.

Based on the `upload_to`, I am expecting to see images uploaded to see images under either:
`myproject/photos` or `myproject/media/photos` correct?

Am I doing anything obvious wrong here?  How do I get my images to upload?

--------------settings.py-------------

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/me/django_projects/myproject/media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

--------------model.py-------------

```
class Person(models.Model):
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos', blank=True, null=True)

    #  save executes but no image is saved.
    #  Because images are uploaded along with a new entry, I needed a special
    #  work around to get the self.id
    def save(self):
        for field in self._meta.fields:
            if field.name == 'image':
               if self.id is not None:
                 #save image now
                 field.upload_to = 'photos/%d' % self.id
               else:
                 #Save image later
                 saveImageLast = True
        super(Customer, self).save()  # should create self.id if not already
        if saveImageLast == True:
            field.upload_to = 'photos/%d' % self.id
            super(Customer, self).save()
            print "save complete"  #prints, but no image ...?
```

--------------forms.py-------------

```
class PersonForm(ModelForm):

  class Meta:
      model = Person
      fields = ( 'lastName', 'firstName', 'image' )
```

Comment: see here could be a permission issue if code is correct : https://stackoverflow.com/a/73045506/3904109

Answer (score 13):

from django documentation, i think this can help (in the past this helped me):

> Firstly, in order to upload files, you'll need to make sure that your
>    element correctly defines the enctype as "multipart/form-data"

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/foo/">
```

Comment: I made sure that my form includes the enctype as "multipart/form-data". But still no upload.  :(

Answer (score 5):

In your view where you create an instance of the form with post data, ensure you have provided request.FILES

```
form = PersonForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit late, but 'upload_to' is not a method.  It's an attribute that represents the relative path from your MEDIA_ROOT.  If you want to save an image in the folder 'photos' with the filename self.id, you need to create a function at the top of your model class.  For instance:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    def file_path(instance):
        return '/'.join(['photos', instance.id])
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=file_path)
```

Then when you are actually saving your image you would call:

```
person = Person(firstName='hey', lasteName='joe')
person.image.save(ImageObject.name, ImageObject)
```

More on the image file objects [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/files/file/#the-imagefile-class).

More on upload_to [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/#filefield).