# Can't Upload Image In Django

Tags: python, django

I have a profile page where I would like to allow a user to upload a profile picture.  I can edit all of the text but cannot upload an image. It works if i add the image via the Admin, but not via the user's profile page on the website.  Note that when created via admin--it is uploading correctly to the directory (profile_image) that i've specified in media folder. I've created some error handling on template page, but the error generated is this: "The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it."  Below is my code:

models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    first_name = models.CharField(default='',max_length=100 )
    last_name = models.CharField(default='',max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    date_birth = models.DateField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
    bio = models.TextField(default='')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image', blank=True)


def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])

post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def edit_profile(request):
    profile = get_object_or_404(models.UserProfile)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.EditProfileForm(data=request.POST, instance=profile)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/accounts/profile')
    else:
        form = forms.EditProfileForm(instance=profile)
        args = {'form':form}
        return render(request, 'accounts/edit_profile.html', args)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm

from . import models


class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.UserProfile
        fields = [
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'date_birth',
            'bio',
            'image',
        ]


class EditProfileForm(UserProfileForm):
    model = models.UserProfile
    fields = [
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'email',
        'date_birth',
        'bio',
        'image',
    ]
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'accounts/media')
```

edit_profile.html

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}User Profile | {{ user }}{{ super }}{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<h1>My Profile</h1>

<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p}}
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The file comes in **`request.FILES`**, not **`request.POST`**. Do the following in the view:

```
form = forms.EditProfileForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES, instance=profile)
```

See the [documentation on file uploads](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads):

> A view handling this form will receive the file data in **`request.FILES`**, which is a dictionary containing a key for each **`FileField`** (or **`ImageField`**, or other **`FileField subclass`**) in the form.

Comment: Yup--that's it.  Thank you kindly--a big help.

Comment: Never forget to add "enctype='multipart/form-data'" in the corresponding <form> on your template, otherwise you'll scratch your head till there's not a single line of hair on it if there are still some.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your **folder permissions also**, DRF is not throwing any permission errors for me.

For Mac use : `sudo chmod 777 *`
For Live Server don't use this just check what is relevant and secure for your Os.