# I can't upload images with django

Tags: django

I am creating an image upload function with django.
However, it is not uploaded.
I don't know the code mistake, so I want to tell you.
I tried variously, but if I specify default for imagefiled,
default will be applied.

```
#form
class RecordCreateForm(BaseModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = URC
        fields = ('image','UPRC','URN',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(RecordCreateForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['URN'].queryset =  UPRM.objects.filter(user=user)
```

```
#view
class RecordCreate(CreateView):
    model = URC
    form_class = RecordCreateForm
    template_name = 'records/urcform.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('person:home')

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
      kwargs = super(RecordCreate, self).get_form_kwargs()
      # get users, note: you can access request using: self.request
      kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
      return kwargs

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = self.request.user
        form.instance.user = user
        form.instance.group = belong.objects.get(user=user).group
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

```
#model
def get_upload_path(instance, filename):
  n = datetime.now()
  prefix = "records/"
  ymd='/'.join([n.strftime('%Y'), n.strftime('%m'), n.strftime('%d'), ""]) + "/"
  directory=str(instance.user.id) + "/"
  name=str(uuid.uuid4()).replace("-", "")
  extension=os.path.splitext(filename)[-1]
  return ''.join([prefix, directory, ymd, name, extension])

class URC(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(group, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    URN = models.ForeignKey(UPRM, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    UPRC = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_path)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.UPRC
```

```
#urls
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I will post any other necessary code.
Sorry for the poor English.

**Postscript**

The page is redirected without any error display.
But admin screen was able to upload.

```
class BaseModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs.setdefault('label_suffix', '')
    super(BaseModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

```
#template
<form method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.image.label_tag}}
    {{form.image}}
    {{form.UPRC.label_tag}}
    {{form.UPRC}}
    {{form.URN.label_tag}}
    {{form.URN}}
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Can you give some more details about what exactly is happening? Is the `form_valid()` method called? Is a URC object created in the database (check in your django admin site)? How do you notice the image is not uploaded? Are you seeing an error? When you submit the form, what happens in your browser, do you get redirected to the 'person:home' view?

Comment: And `RecordCreateForm` should subclass `ModelForm`, not `BaseModelForm`.

Comment: I added the necessary part.

Comment: what does it mean "admin screen was able to upload"? When you look at the URC object in admin, is it there? Do you see the image?

Comment: The template could not be uploaded at the moment, and the admin could upload it.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of explanation.

Comment: You're not answering my question, which is: looking at the new URC object in admin, do you see the image? just yes or no. I'm not asking you whether you can upload the image in admin.

Comment: Yes, it is visible.

Comment: Ok, then it's uploaded. All the code you're showing here looks just fine and should work. The problem is with the view/template where you want to display the image. The one where you have `<img src="...">`. Can you show that?

Comment: I'm sorry.
There was one mistake.
When sending in form, the page does not transition to successURL.

Comment: Inside your form template, you should display the errors as well: `{{ form.image.errors }}`, `{{ form.URN.errors }}` etc.. so if the submitted for is not valid, you can see what the errors are. You can also just do `{{ form.errors }}` to show all errors in one place.

Comment: "Image
This field is required. Error. " After selection, the image name is also displayed.

Comment: The image name is displayed, but it is not displayed in the value of input, it is just displayed next to it.
Others are displayed in value, but is there anything related to it?

Comment: It should just be a standard "choose file.." button from your browser, that when you click lets you choose a file in your file explorer/finder. If you look at your HTML source it should be `<input type="file" ...>`

Comment: Your form tag should have `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: I did it! Thank you very much.
thank you for your politeness.
That was a really big help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<form>` tag misses the `enctype`, as explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads):

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: see here could be a permission issue if code is correct : https://stackoverflow.com/a/73045506/3904109

Answer (score -1):

You can take a look at this example.
https://www.pythonsetup.com/simple-file-uploads-django-generic-createview/

```
def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = Author(photo=self.get_form_kwargs().get('files')['photo'])
        self.object = form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Comment: This code makes no sense. What does the first line `self.object = ...` do if you're going to then assign it to `form.save()`?

Comment: [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/file-uploads/#handling-uploaded-files-with-a-model) shows you that using a `ModelForm` with an image field just works, you can just save the form and image is saved.